# Deploy Dashboard to Crystal Reports

Tags: reporting-services, crystal-reports, epicorerp

Is it possible to take a Crystal Reports report created from a BAQ, load it onto an Epicor Dashboard and then deploy it back into Crystal Reports?

What I am looking for is a way to link several reports I have created in CR without using the subreports capabilities in CR since I was informed by Epicor tech support that this is not possible (also tested this out and received an application error).

Overall, I am trying to have 5 or 6 reports linked together so that my end user can enter information into one parameter and receive the appropriate information from each of those reports. I'm not sure what is the best way to go about this, whether the Dash should be used or if there is a better option.

I'm a CR and Epicor newbie, so any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating one "container" report and add all reports as subreports to it. This will not work if your reports already contain subreports because Crystal allows just one level of subreports. Another option is to write your own application or to use a 3rd party viewer.